# Cannot get Tensorboard visualization tool to open

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, rstudio, tensorboard

I cannot get the TensorBoard to open using RStudio and `Keras` package.
I am trying to duplicate the TensorBoard using the `Keras` package with R Studio as shown here: https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tools/tensorboard/tensorboard/

Either I have a problem or I don't understand what needs to be done.
I am using these instructions:

```
# launch TensorBoard (data won't show up until after the first epoch)
tensorboard("logs/run_a")

# fit the model with the TensorBoard callback
history <- model %>% fit(
  x_train, y_train,
  batch_size = batch_size,
  epochs = epochs,
  verbose = 1,
  callbacks = callback_tensorboard("logs/run_a"),
  validation_split = 0.2
)
```

I get this error after running `tensorboard("logs/run_a")`:

```
> tensorboard("logs/run_a")
Error in if (tensorboard_version() < "2.0") { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

I have tried these versions:

```
    tensorboard("/Users/kevinwilliams/Documents/r-studio-and-git/MNIST/logs/run_a")
    tensorboard("logs/run_a")
    tensorboard(log_dir = "logs/run_a")
    tensorboard(log_dir = "logs/run_a", launch_browser = TRUE)`
```

The TensorBoard will not open.
The files structure of "logs" and "logs/run_a" was automatically created by these commands.

Training and Validation "events" are being saved to the file locations.

"fitting" the model does run and execute with no error.  The output is sent to the RStudio Viewer and not to the TensorBoard.

Keras V2.7.0

RStudio 1.4.1717

R 4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

It is just a file logging me even plots with matlibplot

```
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='accuracy')
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], label = 'val_accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.ylim([0, 1]) # 0.5 - 1
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
```

Can you see there is some logging generated at target folder where you specific or checkpoints when you read it.?
Only using a tf.profile services to communicate with sub-services they already listening.

```
options = tf.profiler.experimental.ProfilerOptions(host_tracer_level = 3,
       python_tracer_level = 1, device_tracer_level = 1)
tf.profiler.experimental.start(log_dir, options = options)
tf.profiler.experimental.server.start(6009) 
tf.profiler.experimental.stop()
```

[image: Defaults Tensornoard]

Comment: Hello, I am not sure I understand your note or you question.  There are "events" being saved in those folders.  I am using R and RStudio, not Matlibplot.  Or maybe I don't know what matlibplot is.

Comment: I am telling you that it is text or target format when you are merge or query, you can use R-Studio that is the same thing me logins and plots into graph.

Comment: I also answer your question that logging format and tensorbnoard is compatible.

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand your notes and it doesn't seem as if you are answering my question.  I am trying to get tensorboard to open using RStudio.

Comment: As text format.